# How does Thresh know about Katniss and Rue's friendship?

Tags: the-hunger-games

Having finished watching the movie but not having read the book, I had a question. During the scene where Katniss goes to retrieve the medicine offered for Peeta's wound at the Cornucopia... (not sure how much is spoiler but will start here to be safe)

> ... she is attacked by the girl from District 2. She is then saved by Thresh who kills the girl but does not continue to attack Katniss because she was friends with Rue. How does he know they were friends? It seems like Rue died before she could ever inform Thresh of her alliance with Katniss.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Thresh overheard Clove talking to Katniss about being Rue's ally:

> And my bow is empty, the last loaded arrow having gone in Clove’s direction. I’m trapped in the glare of his strange golden brown eyes. 
> “What’d she mean? About Rue being your ally?”

Katniss mentions to Thresh that

> she was the one that killed Rue's killer, and also that she sang to her and placed flowers on her body.  After saying this, Thresh decides he believes her and lets her go.

Here's the quote:

> “I — I — we teamed up. Blew up the supplies. I tried to save her, I did. But he got there first. District One,” I say. Maybe if he knows I helped Rue, he won’t choose some slow, sadistic end for me.
>  “And you killed him?” he demands.
>  “Yes. I killed him. And buried her in flowers,” I say. “And I sang her to sleep.”

Comment: Hm, they seemed to skip over that in the movie. He doesn't really stay around long enough for a conversation. He just kinda kills the girl, mentions "just this time, for Rue" and then runs off which is what confused me.

Comment: It's true, the movie did imply that Thresh had some way of knowing what happened with Rue.  If you've read the book before watching the movie, as I did, I guess you tend to gloss over some of the missing bits.

Comment: They compressed a lot of these moments, unfortunately. :(

Comment: @TheJug In the movie Thresh overhears District 2 taunting Katniss about Rue, and that's how he knows.

Answer (score 14):

Thresh heard Clove say: "It's too bad you couldn't save your friend. What was her name? Rue? Well, we killed her, and now we're gonna kill you."

Comment: Hi and welcome to the SciFi StackExchange site. Could you add in your answer where you found this quote? Which book and chapter?

Comment: @Damien I'm pretty sure that the quote came from the movie. The OP asked specifically about where Thresh found this out in the movie.

Comment: You are absolutely correct! I'll upvote your answer then.

Comment: Clove pretty much says the same thing in the books too.

Answer (score 8):

In the book, Thresh doesn't know that Katniss and Rue teamed up until

> Katniss tells him at the point of a spear, after Thresh had already killed Clove. He probably would have killed Kat outright too, except he'd heard something Clove said about Kat and Rue being allied, and gave Kat a chance to explain.

This point in the movies was trimmed; it's plausible that

> Thresh heard enough of Clove's monologue to Katniss after their struggle to know that Katniss had teamed with Rue and tried to protect her.

Also, since in the movies we don't see hovercraft retrieving the bodies of fallen tributes, we may also believe

> that Thresh came across Rue's body, decorated with flowers, and deduced that of the remaining tributes in the Games by that point, Katniss was the most likely to do that for a fellow tribute. Think about it: it would likely have been a girl and not a Career who would first want to befriend Rue and then to give her a funeral of sorts, which narrows it quickly to Foxface and Katniss, and Foxface hadn't been seen by anyone for more than a couple of seconds at a time since the bloodbath. Also, Thresh would have known that Katniss stepped in to take the place of her younger sister, and Rue was about the same age as Prim, making it even more likely that if anyone besides Thresh cared that Rue had died, it was Kat.

Comment: I forgot Clove mentioned Rue and her being friends. I only remembered Thresh wanting to kill her cause she said she killed Rue.

Answer (score 1):

My answer is Thresh over heard Clove saying

> It's too bad you couldn't help your little friend.

I think after he heard her say that he got really angry.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe when Rue was off lighting fires to distract the careers so Katniss could blow up their stuff she ran into Thresh, he asked what she was doing, and she told him she teamed with Katniss.

Comment: This looks pretty speculative. Do you have a source to support this?

Answer (score -4):

I  really think that Thresh got a balloon thing from a Sponsor or his District that said that Rue was with Katniss. Because it is true that everyone except alliances gets one if that makes sense.

Comment: uh what????????

Comment: @DVK-on-Ahch-To The "balloon thing" is a parachute.

Comment: Is there any quote from the book to back this up? This is an interesting point of view that I had never considered.